Was removing the vertical 4x4 supports between the floor and shelves safe?
In my house, the shelves in this picture were originally supported by three 4x4s vertically from the floor. The shelves were also lower. I wanted to create space under the shelves high enough that I can walk there, so I moved the shelves higher cutting the ceiling-to-shelves 2x4s shorter and removed the floor support 4x4s all together. I am now wondering if I structurally meaningfully weakened the support of the shelves. I intentionally don't put very heavy items on the shelves now. My guess is that the joists are 2x6s, but not sure. I guess what I am asking is - is this hanging support setup strong enough to carry significant weight, like could I safely put myself on those shelves? I think it should be okay, but not sure. Thanks!


put these three things together ... https://www.homedepot.com/p/Superstrut-3-8-in-x-10-ft-Strut-Fitting-Galvanized-Threaded-Electrical-Support-Rod-ZR1038/100207537 ... https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-3-8-in-16-TPI-Zinc-Rod-Coupling-Nuts-822281/204337391 ... https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hillman-3-8-in-16-x-3-in-Hanger-Bolt-6-Pack-44952/204775083

Aren't these rods that would screw into the joists? That is currently handled by the vertical 2x4s. Am I missing something?

add some more vertical supports

Depends on how that is attached to the wall and ceiling, depends on how much load you're putting on it, depends on how it's constructed.
Obviously, you have gotten away with it so far. But I don't think anyone here can tell you how much load it will be able to handle, or when and how a failure might occur, without examining it.
There may be things you can do to strengthen it, such as putting real shelf supports under it and making sure that it, and they, are firmly anchored to the structure. Without knowing all the details, I hesitate to make specific suggestions.
I will point out that generally, people don't add supports to something that they think will be reliable without them. Though, admittedly, homeowners tend to either over design or under design.

Thank you. I'll add that the 2x4s off the ceiling are incredibly sturdy. They don't move at all vertically or sideways. The shelve is anchored through a 2x4 running horizontally along the wall. Each stud has 3 strong screws supporting the shelves. When I do a pull up by the suspended edge of the shelves, nothing moves a bit. It all feels very sturdy. Also, the short side behind the camera is also firmly screwed into the wall.

The ceiling support may be sufficient for the load you are putting on that shelf. We really can't tell from the photo. From your description, I would trust it with moderate weight unless you are in an earthquake zone.

I am in an earthquake zone, actually. I check it after each quake. I think I'll keep using it for low to medium level load. Mostly bulky stuff. Not things like lumber storage. Thanks again.
